# Node.js; coloured text from stdout gets converted to object notation when written to a file

Tags: node.js, stdout, command-line-interface

Strangely when I save stdout from a node application that produces coloured text, the coloured text gets converted to an object. It seems like the ascii colour codes are being interpreted as some sort of array like, and then written to the file in object notation form.

This is what the output looks like when stdout sent to the terminal.
[image]

And this is what the output looks like after being piped to a file, then the file is viewed with the cat command.
[image]

Does anyone understand what is happening here?

EDIT: Here is the [CLI script source](https://gist.github.com/RobertWHurst/0607965ef4aad12d549e) so you can see how the text is generated.

EDIT 2: Here is the code that the electron module provides, used to colour the text:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, color,
  { get: function () {
      if (noColors || !self.opts.useColors) return this;
      return '\033[' + colors[color] + 'm' + this + '\033[0m';
    }
  , configurable: true
});
```

EDIT 3: I submitted a pull request to [Electron](https://github.com/logicalparadox/electron) to fix this issue, and it has since been merged as of version 0.4.1. I recommend it if you're looking to build a CLI.

Comment: It is not the ascii color codes, it is the characters that make up that "Loom" banner. Perhaps you can show how you are producing the output.

Comment: @MarkkuK Sure, I'll update the question with the code used.

Comment: It is possible to determine if output goes to a terminal-like or a file (block)-like output device. Since you get a JSON formatted output when redirecting to a file, that *must* be intentional. (I.e., it's not the usual way programs behave.)

Comment: @Jongware Yeah, I thought that might be the case. Doesn't make much sense otherwise. Maybe node does something special when sending to a file. Checking the node.js docs...

Comment: .. That said: unfortunately/fortunately, simple coloring added with escape codes with Ionică Bizău's [couleurs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165569/get-ansi-color-for-character-at-index) get redirected as their actual escape codes, using `node` on my Mac. So it should be something in your version or libraries.

Comment: @Jongware Yeah, you're right, It was a bug in the library I was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Node detects if stdout is pointed at the terminal. If it is, it sets stdout to TTY mode. The module responsible for colouring the text, electron, uses TTY boolean on stdout to set the value of `self.opts.useColors` in the code below. If the stdout is pointed at a file, then `self.opts.useColors` is false, and as a result the value of `this` is returned. Here lies the issue. `this` is an object, not a string as the author expected. Replacing `return this` with `return this + ''` resolves the issue by converting `this` into a string.

Broken:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, color,
  { get: function () {
      if (noColors || !self.opts.useColors) return this;
      return '\033[' + colors[color] + 'm' + this + '\033[0m';
    }
  , configurable: true
});
```

Fixed:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, color,
  { get: function () {
      if (noColors || !self.opts.useColors) return this + '';
      return '\033[' + colors[color] + 'm' + this + '\033[0m';
    }
  , configurable: true
});
```